# PowerShell can't catch SharePoint Enable-SPFeature exception

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

While attempting to enable a custom feature in SharePoint 2010 I'm getting an exception that can't be caught, trapped or detected programmatically in PowerShell v2.  I know what the error is and how to fix it in Central Admin but am troubled that the PowerShell deploy script is incapable of identifying this error condition.

```
# This correctly gets the site and feature:
PS C:\> $Error.Clear()
PS C:\> $SiteUrl = 'http://thesite'
PS C:\> $FeatureId = 'D3BF12C5-D342-4F8A-8E86-BB4308699359'
PS C:\> $Site = Get-SPSite | Where { $_.Url -eq $SiteUrl }
PS C:\> $Feature = Get-SPFeature | Where { $_.Id.ToString() -eq $FeatureId }

# But this line produces the error information below it in the console window - in plain color, not red:
PS C:\> $Feature | Enable-SPFeature -url $SiteUrl
Source: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles
Message: Users cannot override privacy while the property is replicable.
Trace:    at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypeProperty.set_UserOverridePrivacy(Boolean value)
       at IHI.Springs.GAC.UserProfile.UserProfilePropertyManager.EnableUserOverridePrivacy(String propertyName)
       at IHI.Springs.GAC.EventReceivers.FeatureReceivers.ProfilePropertyFeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
```

The error message above is written to the console but isn't detectable programmatically:

After running the Enable-SPFeature command, $? is $true, $Error has no errors and $LastExitCode has nothing.

Trying to capture the exception with either try/catch or trap fails.  For the lines below, the error message is still dumped to console but "Error caught!" is never displayed:

```
try { $Feature | Enable-SPFeature -url $SiteUrl } catch { "Error caught!" }    
trap { "Error caught!" } $Feature | Enable-SPFeature -url $SiteUrl
```

And I can't capture that text no matter what I do; none of these work:

Error message is displayed in console, $ErrorInfo is empty:

```
$ErrorInfo = $Feature | Enable-SPFeature -url $SiteUrl 2>&1
$ErrorInfo = $null; $Feature | Enable-SPFeature -url $SiteUrl -ErrorVariable ErrorInfo
```

Error message is displayed in console, ErrorFile.txt is created (expected) but is empty:

```
$Feature | Enable-SPFeature -url $SiteUrl > c:\temp\ErrorFile.txt
```

We are looking into our feature activation code and we do know how to fix this on the server but it's crazy that I can't detect this error programmatically.   The exception is throw by the cmdlet Enable-SPFeature but PowerShell isn't wrapping the exception in an ErrorRecord, isn't writing it to the error pipeline or doing anything useful.  I've been using PowerShell pretty extensively since Monad Beta 2 came out and have seen a lot of funky things but this shakes my confidence in it.  (I don't have any confidence in SharePoint, so nothing lost there).

Comment: Powershell + Sharepoint Error handling. Nice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is kind of a WAG, I have never used any of the SharePoint cmdlets.

Try adding "-ea Stop" (without the quotes) to your Enable-SPFeature command.  That may cause the error to actually be thrown.

IMO, using -ea Stop to force errors to be terminating errors, so they can be caught, is one of the more counter-intuitive features of PowerShell.

Comment: Works!  Many thanks!  When adding -ErrorAction stop, $? is now false, $Error has the ErrorRecord as does $_ in the try/catch. I can't prevent the text from being output to the console (via any redirection) nor is the ErrorVariable being populated.  Not a big deal as long as I have the error info.  Thanks again - using -EA that way is counter-intuitive!